# Unidentified indoor insects in my Click & Grow garden

Tags: identification, indoors, bugs

I am growing a [small click and grow smart garden with 3 pods](https://eu.clickandgrow.com/products/the-smart-garden-3) that my girlfriend was offered. It's been pretty good so far, that's not the best way of growing plants but for some aromatic plants in an apartment, it's really okay!

It's been a few days since insects took over my micro garden and they don't really seem to be there to help me make it thrive. I am really not sure who they are and if they are harmful to my plants. It seems they are having a good time!

[image: Four bugs having a good time on my click and grow 3 pods]

Should I get rid of them? And if so, by what method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are aphids, soft bodied insects that suck plant fluids and spread plant diseases.

Control is easily done with soap and water and persistence.  Create a solution of 5 ml dish soap to 1 liter of water. Spray all leaves and stems or use a cloth to wipe the plant down.

The key to success is to repeat the treatment at five to seven day intervals to catch the next generation as it hatches. Usually an additional two applications will do the job

Answer (score 2):

The other option here would be to buy ladybug nymphs.  They are commercially available.  You can search for "live ladybug nymphs online" or similar.  Once the aphid problem has been resolved, you could release the mature ladybugs to the outdoors.  I'm assuming this is North America but it would be good if you specify your region.